# Dockerized React webapp cannot communicate to local Dockerised Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rest, networking, virtual-machine

To start, i am very new to Docker, so troubleshooting has proven very tricky, and as a last ditch effort i'm hoping someone more knowledgeable than myself can help.

Basically my project has 3 Docker containers running on a Debian VM on Google Cloud platform.

1. MySQL 5.7
2. React Webapp
3. Spring Boot REST API

All three are on the same local bridge network called pms-net. The containers have their ports mapped like so:
[image]

Compose:

[image]

Using the external ip provided through the Google Cloud Platform dashboard you can connect to the site without issue, but whenever you perform an action that would make an API call, it just times out.
[image]

For the IP in the request; ive tried the external ip, the local network ip, localhost, the container id, the subnet ip, subnet gateway, and nothing works. All of them timeout. (The reason for some not working is more evident than others. Just needed to try everything)

My issue arises from the fact that i don't know if my containers are setup incorrectly (or the local network they are on) or if i am just making the API call to the wrong address. I am inclined to believe it is the latter though.

From the VM i can make a cURL via the subnet Gateway (172.18.0.1):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"id": "email@email.com", "password": "password"}' \
    http://172.18.0.1:8080/api/login;
```

And it works just fine. I can do the same with `localhost` and the subnet IP `172.18.0.3`

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. But the rubber duck is no longer talking back, and I'm at a loss. Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't cURL your VM from outside, how about firewall rules for your API. Is it open? Everything looks fine on screen shots.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by firewall rules? I have this all running on a google cloud VM. Are you referring to the VM's firewall rules, or Docker firewall rules? (if thats a thing).

Comment: VM firewall rules

Comment: It appears that all the current rules allow for communications.
https://i.imgur.com/lwdN3QV.png

Comment: In local network you need to use name of container: `http://pms-server-container:8080/api/login`. I though you want to cURL from other machine.

Comment: I can do that from within the react container like so:

```docker exec -it pms-react-container \
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"id": "email@email.com", "password": "password"}' \
    http://pms-server-container:8080/api/login;```

However when i replace the calls in the react image using that address it still fails. This time however it doesn't timeout, but immediately receives a net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: If containers in the same network, use `http://localhost:8080/api/login`

Comment: Unfortunately, like i said in my OP, i have tried localhost:8080, and it does not work.

Comment: Update your OP with docker-compose file

Comment: Updated. However i manually built everything and did not use docker-compose. The setup would be the same.